# Google bigquery runquery samples and the correct way to use while sleep to check the queryresult

Tags: google-bigquery

Google sample codes #1

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/v0.21.1/bigquery/bigqueryclient?method=runQuery

```
$queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery('SELECT commit FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.commits] LIMIT 100');
$isComplete = $queryResults->isComplete();
while (!$isComplete) {
  sleep(1); // let's wait for a moment...
  $queryResults->reload(); // trigger a network request
  $isComplete = $queryResults->isComplete(); // check the query's status
}
foreach ($queryResults->rows() as $row) {
  echo $row['commit'];
}
```

In sample code #1, if there are some errors at Google Bigquery side, then php script will be stuck in a infinite loop, correct?

Google Sample Code #2

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/api/src/functions/run_query.php

```
$queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery(
    $query,
    ['useLegacySql' => $useLegacySql]);
# [END run_query]
# [START print_results]
if ($queryResults->isComplete()) {
    $i = 0;
    $rows = $queryResults->rows();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        printf('--- Row %s ---' . PHP_EOL, ++$i);
        foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
            printf('%s: %s' . PHP_EOL, $column, $value);
        }
    }
    printf('Found %s row(s)' . PHP_EOL, $i);
} else {
    throw new Exception('The query failed to complete');
}
```

In sample code #2, the bigquery might still be running before it is completed but our php code could already throw wrong exception too early.

Would the correct solution be like the following?

```
$counter = 0;
while (!$isComplete && $counter < 100) {
  sleep(1); // let's wait for a moment...
  $queryResults->reload(); // trigger a network request
$isComplete = $queryResults->isComplete(); // check the query's status
  #counter++;
}
```

So we will give bigquery time to finish the query but we will only wait for a reasonable time before we throw error exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently it has been added [ExponentialBackoff](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/blob/06cbd4c02367fe7c5be171d0e4923b7be3102463/src/Core/ExponentialBackoff.php), check out the latest version of the PHP library

your code would be something like:

```
$job = $bigQuery->runQueryAsJob($query);
$backoff = new ExponentialBackoff(8);
$backoff->execute(function () use ($job) {
    $job->reload();
    if (!$job->isComplete()) {
        throw new \Exception();
    }
});
if (!$job->isComplete()) {
    $this->e('Job failed to complete within the allotted time.');
    return false;
}

$queryResults = $job->queryResults();

if ($queryResults->isComplete()) {
    $i = 0;
    $rows = $queryResults->rows();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your proposal looks reasonable. Although you might want to put the jobid to a queue, and let a threadpool thread/timer to check it periodically, instead of just block and sleep in the main thread.
(I'm not familiar with php, so please forgive me if you don't have such kind of utility in the language)